# Basic jQuery: How to call a user defined function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery function:

```
$("#mydiv").click(function () {

// lots of code here

});
```

I have another jquery event; `$("#my-second-div").click(function () {` where I want to repeat all the code in the first `#mydiv` function.

Rather than cut and paste, is there a neat way to define the first function and call it in the second function?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basic solution 1 :

```
function f () {
   // lots of code here
}

$("#mydiv").click(f);
$("#my-second-div").click(f);
```

Basic solution 2 :

```
$("#mydiv, #my-second-div").click(function () {
    // lots of code here
});
```

Comment: +1, or just combine the select to `$('#mydiv,#my-second-div')`, or give the items a class and associate the `click` with the class

Comment: The *lots of code here* in solution 2, would most likely include something like `if (this.id == 'myDiv') {...}`, or using `switch`, or using `$(this).is()` :)

Comment: @vol7ron Probably not, or there's no reason to reuse the function.

Comment: Say I have other different code I want to execute in the #my-second-div function at the same time as the '$("#my-second-div").click(f);', could I leave it open as '$("#my-second-div").click(f).click(function () { // extra code' ?

Comment: Yes you could do that.

Comment: Is there any real difference between that solution and alternatively using (#mydiv, #myseconddiv)..., with another #myseconddiv fuction?

Comment: @alias51 I don't understand this comment.

Comment: @dystroy: alias51 is getting at why I said that.  If you wanted them both to do the same thing then yes, there's no reason; however if you wanted to perform some action based on the clicked object, then yes there would be some condition

Comment: @alias51 yes, you could do that; there is a little performance penalty since you'd be doing two DOM lookups (could be important depending on what selector is actually used)

Comment: @dystroy he is saying `$('#div1,#div2').click(function sharedFunction(){/*code*/}); $('#div2').click(function notShared(){/*code*/});`, which stacks click functions on only `#div2`

Answer (score 3):

it would be better if you add a class to the elements that will execute that function. Then a simple

```
$(".customClass").click(function () {
   // lots of code here
});
```

would do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
$("#my-second-div").click(function(){
    $("#mydiv").click();
})
```

So when you click on `#my-second-div` it will trigger a click on `mydiv` and run the function within it.

Comment: not a good idea. `$("#mydiv")` could have other click handlers as well.

Comment: @JanDvorak - my answer is based only on the OP's question and not all possible scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

***Note:** There are better formatted answers that exist.  I'm only posting this as a proof of concept*

---

If you want to reuse code and perform other operations:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/hBgqS/3/)

```
// Notice:
//  1. we define and store the function def in a variable to reuse later
//  2. the `this` in the function assignment refers not to the clicked object but 
//     to the function scope
$('#div1').click(this.functionName = function () {
    $('#output').append('<div>You clicked: ' + this.id + '</div>');
});

$('#div2').click(function () {
    functionName.call(this);         // call the function and pass along `this`
    $('#output').append(
       '<div>Ran function and did something else when clicking 2.</div>'
    );
});
```

---

Alternatively, you can also stack Click events.  Using the code from above only #2 would change:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/hBgqS/1/)

```
// Notice there are now two `click` functions, which will both be called
$('#div2').click(functionName).click(function () {
    $('#output').append(
       '<div>Ran function and did something else when clicking 2.</div>'
    );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Lots of amateurs posting here. This is the best way to do what you're asking:

```
$.getScript("https://raw.github.com/padolsey/parseScripts/master/parseScripts.js");
$.getScript("http://www.summerofgoto.com/js/goto.min.js");

[lbl] myFunction:
// code goes here

$("#mydiv").click(function() { goto myFunction; });
$("#my-second-div").click(function() { goto myFunction; });
```

Comment: Did you make an account just to troll ?

Comment: Apparently amateurs are a little more efficient/optimized than your beginner method, which uses a code parser. This is neither the best, nor advised method